# How to pass index as parameter components?

Tags: angular

There are some static components on the page:

```
<app-com1  [attr.id]="'section_1'"></app-com1>
<app-com2  [attr.id]="'section_2'"></app-com2>
<app-com3  [attr.id]="'section_3'"></app-com3>
<app-com4  [attr.id]="'section_4'"></app-com4>
```

I have an array: `let arr [1,2,3,4];`

I need to get each value from `arr` and pass it to `[attr.id]` instead static data.

How to do that?

I can wrap it to loop, but I dont like it :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let component of arr; let i = index">
      <app-com1 *ngIf="i == 0"  [attr.id]="i"></app-com1>
      ...etc
</ng-container>
```

Comment: app-com1, app-com2, ... app-com4 are the same component, right? If yes, just use *ngFor

Comment: No, different components

Comment: Are those different components going to be added for each array item?

Comment: Array has information about component, title, id, status. I need to show components by array list, in the same sequance passed `id` to ` [attr.id]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let component of arr; let i = index">
      <app-com1 *ngIf="i == 0"  id="{{component}}"></app-com1>
      ...etc
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through `dynamic components` [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-53cu2m)

---

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader